# How to apply a default active class for second list item

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry if the grammer/terminology I use is off, I am new to html, css, etc. I want the second list item in my ul to be active when you load the page. How do I do this.

This is my html:

```
  <ul class="quantity-grid">
           <li class="1bag" value="1">
               <h3>1 BAG, $35</h3>
           </li>

           <li class="2bags" value="2">
               <h3>2 BAGS, $45</h3>
           </li>

           <li class="3bags" value="3">
               <h3>3 BAGS, $65</h3>
           </li>

           <li class="4bags" value="4">
               <h3>4 BAGS, $55</h3>
           </li>
  </ul>
```

This is my css:

```
 .quantity-grid li{
    border:4px solid transparent;
    margin:3%;
    overflow:hidden;
 }

 .quantity-grid li.active{
   border:4px solid #fff;
 }
```

And this is my JS:

```
 $("ul.quantity-grid li").click(function(){
      $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
 });
```

Not really sure where to begin..

Comment: Add active class in html to the 2nd li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do this... on page load second element should have class `"active"`

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul.quantity-grid li:nth-of-type(2)").addClass("active");
    });
```

Either you do this by `nth-of-type` if you always want 2nd element to be active `OR` do it using `class="2bags active"`in html else in jQuery itself

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".2bags").addClass("active");
    });
```

Comment: This is a bit of overkill. to use code to add a class on start with, whereas you can just add `active` class to the second item in the html.

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa thats what i said in comments on ques. dont know why he/she is not doing that!

Comment: Probably doesn't have access to the markup, or he making an add-in, other than that i don't understand either.

Answer (score 0):

`.active` means when the element is focused, used usually for textBoxes, you simple need to add a styling with a class name `active` and it should work.

```js
$("ul.quantity-grid li").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.quantity-grid li {
  margin: 3%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.active {
  border: 4px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="quantity-grid">
  <li class="1bag" value="1">
    <h3>1 BAG, $35</h3>
  </li>

  <li class="active 2bags" value="2">
    <h3>2 BAGS, $45</h3>
  </li>

  <li class="3bags" value="3">
    <h3>3 BAGS, $65</h3>
  </li>

  <li class="4bags" value="4">
    <h3>4 BAGS, $55</h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```